# How to get attribute value with jQuery and extract substring from a result

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a list of text inputs whose values I want to manipulate based on the values of some select inputs. The two sets of inputs have IDs with parallel constructions, such as:

```
<select id="foo-dog-bar>, <input type="text" id="foo-dog-baz>
<select id="foo-cat-bar>, <input type="text" id="foo-cat-baz>
<select id="foo-fish-bar>, <input type="text" id="foo-fish-baz>
<select id="foo-bird-bar>, <input type="text" id="foo-bird-baz>
```

In order to be able to find the matching text input, I need to search for the select input with corresponding ID. In the above example, that's the ID with the same animal name in the middle of it.

Here is what I have so far, with my question being what to do about the `criteria` variable:

```
jQuery('select[id$="-points"]').change(function() {

    var value = jQuery(this).val(),
        arr = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'bird'],
        criteria = jQuery(this)..., // whichever string in arr its ID contains
        bar = jQuery(this).parent().find('#foo-'+criteria+'-bar').val();

    // do stuff...

});
```

How can I search the ID of `this` for a string contained in the `arr` array and make that string the `criteria` variable? The only thing I can find when searching for this type of thing is retrieving the index of the array items, but that doesn't help me here. I want the actual string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, I won't ask you to post the HTML, but I really don't understand your question, and your write-up isn't clear without it.

Comment: _Also, the HTML is really not relevant here_ if you don't want to post your html, create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with pseudocode. If you don't want to do this, don't ask a question here

Comment: Apologies, I realized I left out a crucial piece of info originally. I have edited the question to try to be more clear and detailed. If you have more specific questions, please let me know what is unclear. The total HTML structure truly seems irrelevant to me. I can post it if necessary, but when I have posted it in a similar question to this one, it only distracted from my question and led the answers off track. In this case, I just want to know how I can search an input's ID for a string in an array of possible strings and set that string as the `criteria` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To select an id attribute value of html tag

   ```
   criteria = jQuery(this).attr('id'); // just call an .attr('id');
   ```
2. To select element by ID with jQuery - just as with pure JS(javascript), you do not need to find element within nested elements as ID is a unique element per DOM/PAGE

   ```
   jQuery('#foo-'+criteria+'-bar').val();
   ```
3. You can use split function to get values from the string:

   `criteria = criteria.split('foo-')[1].split('-baz')[0];`

Full example:

```
   jQuery('select[id$="-points"]').change(function() {
         var value = jQuery(this).val(),
         arr = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'bird'];
         criteria = jQuery(this).attr('id'); 
         criteria = criteria.split('foo-')[1].split('-baz')[0]; // get the value you want using split() function
         bar = jQuery('#foo-'+criteria+'-bar').val();
         // do other stuff...
    });
```

Comment: Whoever gave me a negative score - comment here the reason.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but that does not help me as I cannot use the `criteria` variable as you have it. I need to match two elements based on a string their IDs have in common; calling one element by its ID alone is unhelpful. I will edit the question to try to clarify.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I needed. I got the function working now :)